# ACM conference template: auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf, microtype, acm

I am workin on ACM conference template (`sample-sigconf.tex`) from [HERE](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) 
I am using WinShell editor. The script compiles fine but when I click PDFView, I get this error:

```
test.tex(34): Error: pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
test.tex(1): Error:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The error can only be resolved if I add this package: `\usepackage{lmodern}`. However, I have been told that does would result in non compliance output with the conference proceedings formats.

How can I resolve these errors? what is their cause?

Here is a sample script:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %to solve the font error
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{lmodern}  %to solve the font error

% Copyright
%\setcopyright{none}
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}

\begin{document}
\title{Tests}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Inst.}}
\email{author@inst}


\begin{abstract}
Abstract 
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum
%\FloatBarrier %to make references always at the end
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography} 

\end{document}
```

EDIT: This might help you. This part from the end of the log:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\libertine\ts1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd"
File: TS1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd 2017/03/20 (autoinst) Font definitions for TS1/
LinuxLibertineT-TLF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TS1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.0pt on input line 130.
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `LinuxLibertineT-TLF' (encoding: TS1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.95pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/it' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TS1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/it' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.0pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.2pt on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.0pt on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.3pt on input line 134.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.5pt on input line 134.

[1.1{C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}


! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv 

l.141 \begin{itemize}
```

Comment: Do you get any warning about fonts in the log file?

Comment: The `acmart` class uses Linux Libertine as the main font, which is only available in outline format (as opposed to bitmap, that would trigger the error you mention). My guess is that you don't have Linux Libertine properly installed in your TeX system, so LaTeX tries a font substitution and chooses the `cmr` family; however, you probably don't have the corresponding outline font (extended guess: you're on MiKTeX), so bitmap fonts are eventually used.

Comment: @egreg I am using Windows and MiKTeX. So, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: @egreg And yes, the log contains warnings about font. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Please, add the contents of the log file up to the first warning about fonts.

Comment: acmart has a `\RequirePackage{microtype}`, so this is a microtype problem.

Comment: "ACM is happy to provide authors working with LATEX class and Word files technical help. Please direct your technical query to: acmtexsupport@aptaracorp.com

All email queries will be responded to within 24 hours."

Comment: I agree with @egreg that this probably is a problem with the fonts not properly installed. What happens if you put `\microtypesetup{expansion=false}` into the preamble?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem came from package `microtype`, and the comment from @Robert solved this issue :

```
\microtypesetup{expansion=false}
```

Comment: But make sure you have the `libertine` fonts properly installed. That’s a better solution.